# get the statistics in a text file using awk

Tags: awk

I have a text file like this small example:

```
>chr10:101370300-101370301
A
>chr10:101370288-101370289
A
>chr10:101370289-101370290
G
>chr10:101471626-101471627
g
>chr10:101471865-101471866
g
>chr10:101471605-101471606
a
>chr10:101471606-101471607
g
>chr10:101471681-101471682
```

as you see below every line that starts with `">"` I have a letter. these letters are `A, G, T or C`. in my results I would like to get the frequency of them in percentage. here is a small example of expected output.

```
A = 28.57
G = 14.29
g = 42.85
a = 14.29
```

I am trying to do that in `awk` using :

```
awk 'if $1 == "G", num=+1  { a[$1]+=num/"G" }
     if $1 == "G", num=+1  { a[$1]+=num/"C" }
     if $1 == "G", num=+1  { a[$1]+=num/"T" }
     if $1 == "G", num=+1  { a[$1]+=num/"A" }
' infile.txt > outfile.txt
```

but it does not return what I want. do you know how to fix it?

Comment: There are various inconsitencies in your post. You mention four characters "A","G","T" or "C" but your example already shows two more "a" and "g". Your expected output does not mention "T" or "C". Furthermore, in your `awk` script you, you divide numbers by characters like `num/"G"`, what do you expect this returns?

Answer (score 2):

**`Awk`** solution:

```
awk '/^[a-zA-Z]/{ a[$1]++; cnt++ }
     END{ for (i in a) printf "%s = %.2f\n", i, a[i]*100/cnt }' file.txt
```

- `/^[a-zA-Z]/` - on encountering records that only starts with a letter `[a-zA-Z]`:

  - `a[$1]++` - accumulate occurrences of each item(letter)
  - `cnt++` - count the total number of items(letters)

The output:

```
A = 28.57
a = 14.29
G = 14.29
g = 42.86
```

Answer (score 0):

you sample is in contradiction with your comment (every line starting with > have no letter on my display, so i assume it's a copy/paste translation error)

```
awk '{C[$NF]++;S+=0.01} END{ for( c in C ) printf( "%s = %2.2f\n", c, C[c]/S)}' infile.txt > outfile.txt
```

if line are well under like the sample add 'NF==1' as first part of the awk code

Comment: Be aware that `0.01 ~ 0.010000000000000000208166817117216851329430937767029`